# Another "package does not exist" error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have the following:

~/java/sources/com/fancy/widgets/spinner.java

```
    package com.fancy.widgets;
    public class spinner {
    ...
    }
```

~/java/sources/com/fancy/fancy.java

```
    import com.fancy.widgets.spinner;
    ...
```

~/java/classes/com/fancy/widgets/spinner.class

When I try to compile fancy.java as follows I get an error:

```
    ~/java/sources/com/fancy: javac -classpath '.:~/java/classes' fancy.java

    fancy.java:9: error: package com.fancy.widgets does not exist
```

I've read the doc on classpath and reading the answers to similar questions here hasn't helped.  What did I do wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Does `javac -classpath`  handle the ~ notation? It probably doesn't. Try the actual path.

Comment: You’ve only put the classes directory in your path. If you want to compile both classes from source, you also need to include the sources directory, either also in the classpath argument, or as a separate -sourcepath argument. And your current directory should be ~/java/sources

Comment: not your problem, but java conventions sasy that class names must start with an upper case letter...

Comment: Paul is correct.  The `javac` command won't do tilde expansion.  And since  you put the classpath argument inside single quotes, neither will the shell.  Use the expanded pathnames ...

Comment: Btw. OP, please use proper Java naming conventions: Class names are to begin with an upper case character. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Thank you Paul Hicks (and Stephen C) for the correct answer.  The tilde was the problem.  I'm new to StackOverflow but I suspect the proper etiquette is for you to submit the answer so I can mark it correct.